# How do I style the Bootstrap .card element so it does not expand into the header or footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require html.sortable
//= require cocoon
//= require gritter
//= require cable
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

```css
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
@import "gritter";

/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

h1, .h1,
h2, .h2,
h3, .h3,
h4, .h4,
h5, .h5,
h6, .h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 65rem;
  }
}

/*
* Custom styles
*/

.card-body {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.auth-links a {
  color: black;
}

.actions {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.register-text {
   text-align: right;
}

.login > .card {
  width: 22rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.app-nav span {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 82%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 148%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: image-url('home_coding.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.app-footer {
  color: white;
}

.tech-news {
  color: black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.tech-news a {
  color: green;
}

.tech-news > .card {
  padding: 10px;
}

.app-card-container {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

.app-card-container > .card {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.profile-img {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.app-card-container a {
  color: blue;
}
.skill {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <h1>About Me</h1>

  <hr>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= image_tag "profile.jpg", width: 300, alt: "profile image", class: 'profile-img' %>

    <div class="skills">
     <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
      <div class="skill">
       <h4><%= skill.title %></h4>
       <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning" role="progressbar" area-valuenow="<%= skill.percent_utilized %>" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= skill.percent_utilized %>%"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     <% end %>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-8">
    <p>With almost five years of development experience in a number of industries I realized that the typical product creation process between clients and developers was flawed. All too often developers rarely communicate with clients throughout the development stage, resulting in a final product that fails to reach the goal sought by the customer and end user.</p>

    <p>For this reason I decided to utilize a completely different pattern that focuses on highly focused communication and transparent design patterns. When I take on a project not only do I work to craft the application according to the client's specifications, I give daily updates to ensure that the project is aligning properly with the client's goals. The end result is the right product, delivered on time and on budget.</p>

    <p>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#jobHistory" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="jobHistory">
      Job History
     </button>

     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#education" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="education">
      Education
     </button>
    </p>

    <p>
     <div class="collapse" id="jobHistory">
      <div class="card card-body">
       Solutions Consultant - Setup Linux servers for hosting client WordPress sites as well as some DevOps responsibilities such as deploying multiple servers via Ansible, Docker and Chef.
      </div>
      <div class="card card-body">
       Site Director - Implemented the curriculum for Youth Tech Entrepreneurs, including courses on: A+ Certification, Web Development and Networking.
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="collapse" id="education">
      <div class="card card-body">
       Graduated from University of Massachusetts with an MA in Regional Economic and Social Development
      </div>
      <div class="card card-body">
       Graduated from Rowan University with a BA in Communications.
      </div>
     </div>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>


<footer class="blog-footer">
  <p>
  <%= copyright_generator %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Back to top</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

I am utilizing the Bootstrap .card for my website, but when I add a list of content items inside the .card, it begins to expand down to where it covers the footer. How can I style this card so it will not do that?

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="app-card-container">
    <div class="card">
        <h1>About Me</h1>

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= image_tag "profile.jpg", width: 300, alt: "profile image", class: 'profile-img' %>

                <div class="skills">
                    <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
                        <div class="skill">
                            <h4><%= skill.title %></h4>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning" role="progressbar" area-valuenow="<%= skill.percent_utilized %>" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= skill.percent_utilized %>%"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>Vexillologist twee craft beer palo santo synth. Vexillologist listicle seitan hoodie. 3 wolf moon plaid vice, keffiyeh lyft kombucha leggings brunch iceland unicorn skateboard tote bag. Hella williamsburg asymmetrical paleo pickled gentrify mumblecore hoodie fanny pack air plant DIY. Semiotics edison bulb synth cold-pressed meditation brunch heirloom direct trade live-edge chambray poke.</p>

                <p>Vexillologist twee craft beer palo santo synth. Vexillologist listicle seitan hoodie. 3 wolf moon plaid vice, keffiyeh lyft kombucha leggings brunch iceland unicorn skateboard tote bag. Hella williamsburg asymmetrical paleo pickled gentrify mumblecore hoodie fanny pack air plant DIY. Semiotics edison bulb synth cold-pressed meditation brunch heirloom direct trade live-edge chambray poke.</p>

                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#jobHistory" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="jobHistory">
                        Job History
                    </button>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#education" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="education">
                        Education
                    </button>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <div class="collapse" id="jobHistory">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            Solutions Consultant - Setup Linux servers for hosting client WordPress sites as well as some DevOps responsibilities such as deploying multiple servers via Ansible, Docker and Chef.
                        </div>
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            Site Director - Implemented the curriculum for Youth Tech Entrepreneurs, including courses on: A+ Certification, Web Development and Networking.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse" id="education">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            Graduated from with an MA in Regional Economic and Social Development
                        </div>
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            Graduated from with a BA in Communications.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my application.scss relevant to the above code:

```
    // Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
@import "gritter";

/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

h1, .h1,
h2, .h2,
h3, .h3,
h4, .h4,
h5, .h5,
h6, .h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 65rem;
  }
}

/*
* Custom styles
*/

.card-body {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.auth-links a {
  color: black;
}

.actions {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.register-text {
   text-align: right;
}

.login > .card {
  width: 22rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.app-nav span {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 82%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 148%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: image-url('home_coding.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.app-footer {
  color: white;
}

.tech-news {
  color: black;
  margin: 20px;
}

.tech-news a {
  color: green;
}

.tech-news > .card {
  padding: 10px;
}

.app-card-container {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

.app-card-container > .card {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.profile-img {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.app-card-container a {
  color: blue;
}
.skill {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The footer code is in a partial:

```
<footer class="blog-footer">
  <p>
  <%= copyright_generator %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Back to top</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Create reproducible snippet or jsfiddle please.. also include your footer code

Comment: @ProEvilz, I added the full scss file and the footer partial.

Comment: Please make it a snippet or a jsfiddle so that it actually works.. we need to see the problem in order to fix it. You can create snippets by pressing the editor button on your question and pressing CTRL+M

Comment: @ProEvilz, I created the snippet but its a RoR app so its not going to behave the same in that snippet.

Comment: Seems like it's not interfering with the footer here?

Comment: @ProEvilz, the listing of jobs and schools functions as a dropdown, when that dropdown expands the card expands downwards and covers the footer. You can see the footer still, but its inside the card at that point. I want the card to expand without super imposing itself on the footer or the header. It was doing it with the header but I added margin-top which took care of it.